# DocumentDB: Is it possible to remove auto generated tags, _Etag, _ts etc?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-api-apps

I'm querying my docDb from a api-app using the .NET SDK and when selecting I get these tags which I prefer not to get.
Basically I'm wondering if it's possible to remove the auto generated tags _Etag, _ts, _rid, _attachments etc?

The reason behind this is that I want to convert the JSON output from a Select query into XML, were _tags isn't allowed? If anyone has a different approach, please let me know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated**

There is no way to automatically suppress these when using `SELECT * FROM...`. Here are a few options on how to deal with this:

1. Specify the fields that you do want back in your query
2. Remove them once the data is received by either `obj.Remove("_rid");` for .NET, `delete obj._rid` for Node.js, or copying the key/value pairs to a new dynamic object skipping the keys that start with "_".
3. Create a stored procedure (sproc) which does #2 server-side
4. **Update** Use a user-defined-function (UDF), see below

I now believe that using a UDF is the best way to do this.

```
function stripUnderscoreFields (o) { 
  output = {};

  for (key in o) {
    value = o[key];
    if (key.indexOf('_') !== 0) {
      output[key] = value;
    }
  }
  return output 
}
```

Then use the UDF in a query like this:

```
SELECT VALUE udf.stripUnderscoreFields(c) FROM collection c
```

Note, the keyword `VALUE` in the example above suppresses the $1 prefixes that are added before each document if you leave it out.

Comment: I'm using a stored procedure so step 2 worked after some testing!
Thx alot!

Comment: If you are using .NET sdk this can be solved by removing these tags after 
Client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync

example:
obj.Remove("_rid");

Comment: Added your example into the answer. Thanks!